# Simple interceptor that will fetch all requests and add the jwt token to its authorization header

Tags: angularjs, django-rest-framework, jwt

In my efforts to setup login required to protected pages and reroute to the login page if not authorized, while using Django REST Framework and DRF-JWT, I am trying to go through the following tutorial:

https://www.octobot.io/blog/2016-11-11-json-web-token-jwt-authentication-in-a-djangoangularjs-web-app/

I am not sure what this looks like in step 3 of the front-end section.

```
// Add a simple interceptor that will fetch all requests and add the jwt token to its authorization header.
```

Can someone provide an example?

Also, my original post regarding the issues I am having setting this up in general.

[Trying to get login required to work when trying to access protected pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45490619/trying-to-get-login-required-to-work-when-trying-to-access-protected-pages)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The interceptors are service factories that are registered with the
>   $httpProvider by adding them to the $httpProvider.interceptors array.
>   The factory is called and injected with dependencies (if specified)
>   and returns the interceptor.

The basic idea behind **intercepter** is that it will be called before each $http request and you could use a service to check if user is logged in and add a token or anything else that needs to be added into the header.You could also add some logic for **response for each $http request**, like handling the response based on status code.

Here is how you can use it in angular for adding the access token for each http request.

```
angular.module('myapp')
.run(['$rootScope', '$injector', function($rootScope,$injector) {
    $injector.get("$http").defaults.transformRequest = function(data, headersGetter) {
      if (sessionService.isLogged()) {
        headersGetter()['Authorization'] = "Bearer " + sessionService.getAccessToken();
      }
      if (data) {
        return angular.toJson(data);
      }
    };
});
```

Here is how you can use **response intercepter**:

```
angular.module('myapp')
.factory('authHttpResponseInterceptor', function($q, $location, sessionService, $http) {
  return {
    response: function(response) {
      //some logic here
      return response || $q.when(response);
    },
    responseError: function(rejection) {
      if (rejection.status === 401) {
        //some logic here
      }
      return $q.reject(rejection);
     }
  }
});
```